# maven doesn't recognize my "thrift" dependency?

Tags: java, maven, package, thrift

I'm using IntelliJ for a java application, trying to use apache thrift.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>
        <artifactId>libthrift</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then I used thrift to generate a java file, try to compile the whole project. But
while compile "MyServer.java" which 1st line is:

```
import org.apache.thrift.transport.TServerSocket;  
import org.apache.thrift.transport.TServerTransport;  
import org.apache.thrift.server.TServer;  
import org.apache.thrift.server.TServer.Args;
```

"mvn -e compile "says

```
package org.apache.thrift.transport doesn't exist
package org.apache.thrift.server doesn't exist
package org.apache.thrift.server.TServer doesn't exist
```

How should I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `<type>`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>
    <artifactId>libthrift</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Also, if you aren't working on a legacy application which requires thrift 0.9.1 (2013) you might want to use a newer version like 0.11.0 (2018)

Comment: I tried 0.11.0 in pom.xml, removing "type" tag will work!

Comment: The answer is correct, but it would be stronger if you added some information about why this works. It does, because the lib is of type _jar_, and not _pom_, and _jar_ is the default dependency type.